# Long word breaking width in outlook Heavy Client Email

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, salesforce-marketing-cloud

For a project of mine in SFMC, I need to fix issues on emails, especially for outlook heavy client.
The HTML is created by an API call for personalization, and is pretty complexe.

One issue we have is that the client can add some text, and in a case of long single word, it breaks the width.

As you can see below, I tried to fix the  with table-layout: fixed; and only use word-break: break-all; on the , as suggested on a post I saw here.

This won't work, and this issue is causing a lot of other issues.

Here is the code :

````
<tr>
<td align='center' valign='top' style='word-break: break-all;'>
<table align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='520' class='w285' style='font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; word-break: break-all; table-layout:fixed;'><tr><td align='left' valign='top' style='line-height:16px; word-break: break-all;' class='copy8'>
<font face='Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif' size='2' color='#000000' class='copy8' style='font-family:Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:10px; letter-spacing:0.5px; text-align:left; line-height:16px;text-transform: uppercase; word-break: break-all;'>
                  @var
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with the below example text and it seems to work just fine. Here's a test results link on Email on Acid: https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/a6dP3W4NJckLQwDWuAEUaM9cdBs0j3hXRAujJbzcNQinQ/list

Could you give more details like which Outlook version are you testing on exactly, and eventually a screenshot and a text example causing problem?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align='center' valign='top' style='word-break: break-all;'>
<table align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' width='520' class='w285' style='font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; word-break: break-all; table-layout:fixed;'><tr><td align='left' valign='top' style='line-height:16px; word-break: break-all;' class='copy8'>
<font face='Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif' size='2' color='#000000' class='copy8' style='font-family:Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size:10px; letter-spacing:0.5px; text-align:left; line-height:16px;text-transform: uppercase; word-break: break-all;'>
Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipisicingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.Duisauteiruredolorinreprehenderitinvoluptatevelitessecillumdoloreeufugiatnullapariatur.Excepteursintoccaecatcupidatatnonproiden,suntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollitanimidestlaborum.
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I just realized that I was tested the email wrong and that I had an old version, I'll close this ticket, thanks for looking it up.